# getting rid of the "connecting lines" in python radar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, radar-chart

I'm trying to create a star plot like the one below using python's matplotlib without the lines connecting the "rays of the star". Is there any way to do this?
Thanks a lot!
Tim

[image]

Comment: How about `ax.scatter(theta, x)` instead of `ax.plot(theta, x)`?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. Generally scatter helps to get rid of the connecting line. However, I'd still like to retain the line connecting the dot to the center of possible.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by using plot in a loop, i.e. plotting just one line at a time. Then, the lines are no longer connected. thanks to all.